# Проблема с grunt

Tags: grunt

Начинаю осваивать грант и сразу же столкнулся с проблемой...
установил:  grunt-contrib-sass,так же установил для него Ruby [отсюда](http://rubyinstaller.org/) и sass.
Файл Gruntfile.js содержит:

```
module.export = function (grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');


grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
        style: {
            files: {
                'www/css/style.css': ['www/scss/style.scss']
            }
        }
    }
});
};
```

Но при выполнении команды `grunt sass` пишет ошибку:

```
grunt sass
Warning: Task "sass" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

В чем проблема? Где я сделал что-то не так?

Answer (score 2):

у вас незарегистрирована задача **sass**

необходимо дописать

```
grunt.registerTask('sass', ['sass']);
```

либо

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);
```

тогда по команде grunt выполниться задача по умолчанию (default)

Comment: Спасибо за попытку помочь, но я уже давно решил эту проблему.....
Проблема заключалась в следующем:    
`module.export = function (grunt) {....` - так было у меня, а надо:  
`module.exports  = function (grunt) {....`